# Additional Text field appear in Tumblr (tumblr API using OAuth) login page in Android version 4?

Tags: android, tumblr

[image]

I am using OAuth to integrate the Tumblr API. It is working properly in all the devices but when I checked this on GT-P6200 updated Android 4 I got the following issue:

When I click on the email field and start to type an extra text field appears in the layout. This disappears when focus is removed from the text field. Also clicking on it makes it disappear.

Did anyone find this issue? Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: can you share the screen shot?

Comment: Tumblr Login using SignPost tutorial : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/920/tumblr-login-using-sign-post/